# Is PhD considered as working experience in USA?

Tags: phd, united-states, industry

I want to apply for an industrial job in my field where needs 5 years of experience and having MS/PhD. The website to apply has specific predetermined options to choose. So, I can't write a note on any field. I finished my Ph.D. in 4 years, can I select "4 years" option for the question about my working experience at my current role? Since this job accepts MS too.

(Unfortunately and interestingly, no contact email is mentioned on this job advertisement that I be able to ask themselves.)

Comment: What's your research field and what's the industry job?

Comment: @Nobody: Both are Computer Science, AI. It is written for the job that they need someone to be able to write codes and does required developments.

Comment: I would say "work experience" means outside of academia.

Comment: Doubtful in general (in US), but possible in an individual case. You need to find a way to get information from them. Organizational websites often have a "contact" link.

Comment: May be company specific. My lab has standards to convert degrees to years of experience to determine what level to hire people into.

Comment: Technically, research assistant as PhD is a part-time job.

Comment: @Part-timeEngineer: So, if I have been paid RA for 24 month, I can mention that I have 24 month experience (or it is less that that since you said it is considered as part time)?

Comment: Yes, of course you can mention that you have 24 months RA experience, and list your job duties and acheivements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there is no universal rule. Some institutions may count every year in which you are employed or a student, while others may not count the student years, but will give you credit separately for having a degree.

To the extent that there is ambiguity, however, it is reasonable to interpret the ambiguity in the way that is most favorable to you. If/when your resume gets in front of a human, they can recalculate things as they see fit.

Comment: I think this answer is the right one- it's worth emphasizing that the cost/benefit of simply putting in the application is probably better without investing time on this detail. Worst that can happen is they desk reject the app.